# Volume levels in waveOutGetVolume and Windows 6.x Mixer applet does not always match

Tags: delphi, winapi, winmm

I've got a small program which plays a sound and I'm using [Trackbar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760145) (a Delphi's VCL wrapper of it, in the fact) to adjust a volume of that sound. Since volume level can be adjusted elsewhere, eg: Windows 7 Mixer applet, I'm polling a volume level of `WAVE_MAPPER` device using Windows Timer to set appropriate trackbar position:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetVolume;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetVolume;
var
  Error: MMRESULT;
  Volume: TVolume;
begin
  {$WARN BOUNDS_ERROR OFF}
  Error := waveOutGetVolume(WAVE_MAPPER, @Volume.Volume);
  {$WARN BOUNDS_ERROR DEFAULT}
  waveOutCheck(Error);
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('Volume = %.8x', [Volume.Volume])));
  {$ENDIF}
  TrackBar1.Position := (Volume.Left + Volume.Right) div 2;
end;
```

<sup>**Remarks:** In the code snippet above `TVolume` structure only facilitates packing left and right channel `WORD` sized volume level values into `DWORD` value expected by [`waveOutGetVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743864) and `waveOutCheck` function facilitates checking an argument for `MMSYSERR_NOERROR` and throwing an exception otherwise.</sup>

So, when I move trackbar in Windows 7 Mixer applet, trackbar in my application reflects the actual volume level, **BUT** when I set volume level to 0 in the Mixer applet described feedback breaks, my application no longer reflects Mixer volume level and remains mute. In the fact [`waveOutGetVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743864) keeps reporting `0x00000000` no matter of level set in the Mixer applet. Can someone enlighten what's happening there? Why setting volume to 0 in the Mixer applet locks waveOut device volume at 0 level for ever?

Not sure if it is related, but I've also noticed what when I press "mute" button in the Mixer applet, my application does not sense the change in the volume level.

Comment: I'm not sure if `[delphi]` tag is of any relevance here... Feel free to untag.

Comment: Tested if changes in wolume mixer is reflected with your code; cannot duplicate here, bouncing from 0 does not stay in 0, and volume change when muted is monitored fine.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you for your input. I think I didn't get the last part. When you change volume thru Mixer applet for the muted application, mute setting automatically reset, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, sorry! now I get it. Yes, when I touch the volume in the mixer, application un-mutes. But I checked this to be the case with other applications too.